# Powershell "Parameter set cannot be resolved" error when executing script

Tags: powershell, parameter-sets

I have a powershell script with rather long parameter sets:

```
Param(
    [Parameter(Position = 0, Mandatory = $true, ParameterSetName = 'Senders')]
    [Parameter(Position = 0, Mandatory = $true, ParameterSetName = 'Recipients')]
    [Parameter(Position = 0, Mandatory = $true, ParameterSetName = 'Global')]
    [Parameter(Position = 0, Mandatory = $true, ParameterSetName = 'Manager')]
    [Parameter(Position = 0, Mandatory = $true, ParameterSetName = 'CatalogueName')]
    [Parameter(Position = 0, Mandatory = $true, ParameterSetName = 'ReapplyPermissions')]
    [Parameter(Position = 0, Mandatory = $true, ParameterSetName = 'OnlyListing')]
    [String]$SharedElement,

    [Parameter(Mandatory = $true, ParameterSetName = 'Senders')]
    [String]$Senders,

    [Parameter(Mandatory = $false, ParameterSetName = 'Senders')]
    [Parameter(Mandatory = $true, ParameterSetName = 'Recipients')]
    [String]$Recipients,

    [Parameter(Mandatory = $true, ParameterSetName = 'Global')]
    [String]$Global,

    [Parameter(Mandatory = $false, ParameterSetName = 'Senders')]
    [Parameter(Mandatory = $false, ParameterSetName = 'Recipients')]
    [Parameter(Mandatory = $false, ParameterSetName = 'Global')]
    [Parameter(Mandatory = $true, ParameterSetName = 'Manager')]
    [Alias("Owner")]
    [String]$Manager,

    [Parameter(Mandatory = $false, ParameterSetName = 'Senders')]
    [Parameter(Mandatory = $false, ParameterSetName = 'Recipients')]
    [Parameter(Mandatory = $false, ParameterSetName = 'Global')]
    [Parameter(Mandatory = $false, ParameterSetName = 'Manager')]
    [Parameter(Mandatory = $true, ParameterSetName = 'CatalogueName')]
    [String]$CatalogueName,

    [Parameter(Mandatory = $true, ParameterSetName = 'ReapplyPermissions')]
    [Switch]$ReapplyPermissions,

    [Parameter(Mandatory = $true, ParameterSetName = 'OnlyListing')]
    [Switch]$OnlyListing,

    [Parameter(Mandatory = $false, ParameterSetName = 'Senders')]
    [Parameter(Mandatory = $false, ParameterSetName = 'Recipients')]
    [Parameter(Mandatory = $false, ParameterSetName = 'Global')]
    [Parameter(Mandatory = $false, ParameterSetName = 'Manager')]
    [Parameter(Mandatory = $false, ParameterSetName = 'CatalogueName')]
    [Parameter(Mandatory = $false, ParameterSetName = 'ReapplyPermissions')]
    [Parameter(Mandatory = $false, ParameterSetName = 'OnlyListing')]
    [Switch]$NoLog,

    [Parameter(Mandatory = $false, ParameterSetName = 'Senders')]
    [Parameter(Mandatory = $false, ParameterSetName = 'Recipients')]
    [Parameter(Mandatory = $false, ParameterSetName = 'Global')]
    [Parameter(Mandatory = $false, ParameterSetName = 'Manager')]
    [Parameter(Mandatory = $false, ParameterSetName = 'CatalogueName')]
    [Parameter(Mandatory = $false, ParameterSetName = 'ReapplyPermissions')]
    [Parameter(Mandatory = $false, ParameterSetName = 'OnlyListing')]
    [String]$Reference,

    [Parameter(Mandatory = $false, ParameterSetName = 'Senders')]
    [Parameter(Mandatory = $false, ParameterSetName = 'Recipients')]
    [Parameter(Mandatory = $false, ParameterSetName = 'Global')]
    [Parameter(Mandatory = $false, ParameterSetName = 'Manager')]
    [Parameter(Mandatory = $false, ParameterSetName = 'CatalogueName')]
    [Parameter(Mandatory = $false, ParameterSetName = 'ReapplyPermissions')]
    [Parameter(Mandatory = $false, ParameterSetName = 'OnlyListing')]
    [Switch]$AskCredentials,

    [Parameter(Mandatory = $true, ParameterSetName = 'Help')]
    [Switch]$Help
)
```

I have tested the functionality of these parameters according to my needs and it works fine except in one particular case: when I run the script with parameters SharedElement, OnlyListing and Reference

```
script.ps1 -SharedElement email.address@domain.com -OnlyListing -Reference "Some string"
```

I always get an error:

> Parameter set cannot be resolved using the specified named parameters

However when I run the script with parameters SharedElement, OnlyListing and NoLog it works fine:

```
script.ps1 -SharedElement email.address@domain.com -OnlyListing -NoLog
```

I have been wondering for months what the problem could be and I haven't been able to find a solution. Can anyone point a hint to help me to resolve the problem?

Thank you very much in advance.
Regards.

Comment: I cannot reproduce the problem with the code you've posted, neither in Windows PowerShell v5.1.18362.145 nor in PowerShell Core 7.0.0-preview.6

Answer (score 0):

After the first comment I copied the code from this web page, pasted it into my script and it worked fine. I compared the script with the previous version  in my SVN repository and there was a difference in the parameter set name "OnlyListing" applied to the $Reference parameter. Apparently both parameter set names were identical but one of them contained a hidden character.

Thank you everybody for the help.